# Writing Bytes to strings.builder prints nothing

Tags: string, go, byte

I am learning go and am unsure why this piece of code prints nothing

```golang
package main

import (
  "strings"
)

func main(){
  var sb strings.Builder
  sb.WriteByte(byte(127))
  println(sb.String())
}
```

I would expect it to print 127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending a byte to the string's buffer, not the characters "127".

Since Go strings are UTF-8, any number <=127 will be the same character as that number in ASCII. As you can see in [this ASCII chart](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html), 127 will get you the "delete" character. Since "delete" is a non-printable character, `println` doesn't output anything.

[Here's an example](https://go.dev/play/p/vTRghrjXqDx) of doing the same thing from your question, but using a printable character. 90 for "Z". You can see that it does print out Z.

If you want to append the characters "127" you can use `sb.WriteString("127")` or `sb.Write([]byte("127"))`. If you want to append the string representation of a byte, you might want to look at using `fmt.Sprintf`.

Note: I'm not an expert on character encoding so apologies if the terminology in this answer is incorrect.